# xuggler in java For merging or concatenating 2 or more videos gives RuntimeException: failed to encode audio

Tags: java, video, video-streaming, xuggler, xuggle

i am working in java. I want to merge or concatenate 2 or more videos into single video so that they can play one after another. I have found the code related to this using xuggler.

```
In below link the whole code is present.
http://onlinejavapapers.blogspot.in/2012/12/xuggler.html
```

while running the above code i am getting RuntimeException exception

```
transcode /home/mobi56/kamini/RoundTable/RoundTable_Kamini/movie.mp4 + /home/mobi56/kamini/RoundTable/RoundTable_Kamini/mov_bbb.mp4 -> /home/mobi56/kamini/RoundTable/RoundTable_Kamini/merged4.mp4
10:47:36.633 [main] WARN  com.xuggle.xuggler - error: sample rate in sample does not match StreamCoder (../../../../../../../csrc/com/xuggle/xuggler/StreamCoder.cpp:1768)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: failed to encode audio
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.encodeAudio(MediaWriter.java:855)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.onAudioSamples(MediaWriter.java:1441)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaToolAdapter.onAudioSamples(MediaToolAdapter.java:106)
    at com.om.MergingVideos$MediaConcatenator.onAudioSamples(MergingVideos.java:241)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.AMediaToolMixin.onAudioSamples(AMediaToolMixin.java:89)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.dispatchAudioSamples(MediaReader.java:628)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.decodeAudio(MediaReader.java:555)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaReader.readPacket(MediaReader.java:469)
    at com.om.MergingVideos.concatenate(MergingVideos.java:170)
    at com.om.MergingVideos.main(MergingVideos.java:49)

i have added following jars.

xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.12.jar
xuggle-xuggler-arch-i686-pc-linux-gnu.jar
commons-cli-1.1.jar,
commons-lang-2.1.jar
logback-core-1.0.0.jar,
logback-classic-1.0.0.jar
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Kamini, hi!
I just add following lib.
For me, it's working

- logback-classic-1.0.0
- jarlogback-core-1.0.6.jar
- slf4j-api-1.6.4.jar
- xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar

Comment: But OP already has added `xuggle-xuggler-5.4.jar`, so adding a logback class is not going to help.

Comment: sorry, but then I use example from xuggle-xuggler (Concatenate Audio And Video).

it's required add all of those lib.